# Store files in the cloud to be accessible by any VPS

Tags: linux, vps, amazon-s3

I often create/delete online VPS machines so storing files there will not be so good.

I want a dedicated online storage like S3 for storing files (scripts, videos etc) to be accessible by any VPS machine.

I wonder how I could mount S3 storage so that I in a VPS machine can run the scripts just as they were native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[s3fs](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon)? It will obviously have higher latency than a local block device, but I've used it from time to time and it works just fine.